# Is singular value matrix uniquely determined up to permuting rows and columns.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition, svd

> Given the SVD $A = U\Sigma V^T$, is $\Sigma$ uniquely determined up to permuting the rows and columns?

My take is that singular value matrix *is* uniquely determined. Its diagonal elements are square roots of eigenvalues of $A^TA$ and $AA^T$ (both of which have the same *unique* *set* of eigenvalues). Thus, $A$ has a *unique set* of singular values.

Permuting rows and columns of $\Sigma$ we just rearrange the singular values along the diagonal of $\Sigma$. SVD will continue to hold if we rearrange corresponding vectors of $U$ and $V$.

However, such reasoning seems to lack rigour.

Answer (score 1):

If an eigenvalue of $A^T A$ or $AA^T$ has multiplicity greater than 1, the corresponding left and right singular vectors are not unique. In this case, the columns of $U$ and $V$ can  be permuted, but one can also choose entirely different left and right singular vectors.

A simple example. 
$$
 \begin{align*}
  \begin{bmatrix} 
   2 &  0 \\
  0 & 2 
  \end{bmatrix}
  &=
\begin{bmatrix} 
   1 &  0 \\
  0 & 1 
  \end{bmatrix}^T
\begin{bmatrix} 
   2 &  0 \\
  0 & 2 
  \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 
   1 &  0 \\
  0 & 1 
  \end{bmatrix} \\
 &=
\begin{bmatrix} 
   \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} &  -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
  \end{bmatrix}^T
\begin{bmatrix} 
   2 &  0 \\
  0 & 2 
  \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 
   \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} &  -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
   \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}& \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
  \end{bmatrix}. \\
 \end{align*}
$$